# Missing feeds plugin after Drupal core update

Tags: commerce, feeds

I have inherited a Drupal site from another developer and since I updated Drupal (Commerce Kickstart) to the lates version I have a warning "Missing Feeds plugin FeedsEntityProcessor..". I am not familiar with wthe Feeds module before so have no idea what is actually missing and where to look for it. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I reverted the feeds module to the version it was before I updated it and now it seems ok again.

Comment: Oké, can you accept my answer so users that stumble on this problem in the future know this was the correct answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this issue, should fix your problem: https://www.drupal.org/node/2397763